# How to call template from another template in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two templates like this ...one to create normal package name and another to append "-Non" with the name if it passes certain conditions as shown

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="checkForAgency">
  <xsl:param name="Name"/>
  <xsl:param name="Agency"/>
  <xsl:if test="contains($Agency,'AG') ">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($Name,' - Non')"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" name="createPackageName">
  <xsl:param name="Type"/>
  <xsl:if test="contains($Type,'NEW')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('New',' Goal')"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="contains($Type,'AMD')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Amended',' Goal')"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="contains($Type,'REN') or contains($Type,'ARN')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Renewal',' Goal')"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling these templates from

```
<xsl:variable name="NonAgencyPackageName">
  <xsl:call-template name="createPackageName">
    <xsl:with-param name="Type" select="ID"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="PackageName">
  <xsl:call-template name="checkForAgency">
    <xsl:with-param name="Name" select="$NonAgencyPackageName"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="Agency" select="Output"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:element>
```

If  ID has 'New', the package name should be New Goal and if the Output has 'AG', then name should be New Goal- Non.
Else name should be new goal. I want it two separate templates only. I am getting empty value now. Please help me in achieving this and how to correct it?

Comment: templates with both `match=` and `name=` I've never seen - it either has `match=` (and maybe `mode=`) or `name=` but not `match=` then, suggest to pull out your xslt book once more :) Or show (editing the question) what your input and expected output xmls look like

Comment: @StefanHegny is right to suggest you check your templates:  unless you are doing something very clever in the rest of the stylesheet (and if you were that clever you wouldn't have this question), it's pointless to have a `match` attribute on the named templates.  Not illegal (templates with both `match` and `name` are just fine), but in this particular case pointless and thus confusing to the maintenance programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, the XPaths `ID` and `Output` are not selecting what you expect, so all conditionals are failing.  Since you don't provide any XML input, it's impossible to be sure.

Ask yourself several questions:

- When this code is evaluated, what is the current element?
- Does this element have a child element named ID?
- What is the string value of that element?
- Does it have a child element named Output?
- What is its string value?

The PackageName element you generate will be non-empty only if there is an Output child and its string value contains the sequence 'AG'.  It will contain the string 'New Goal - Non' only if the Output child contains 'AG' and the ID child contains NEW.  No power in creation could make it have the value 'New Goal', since the template CheckForAgency either produces a value ending with ' - Non' or no output at all.  (You may wish to read about the choose/when instruction in XSLT.)